# how can i make a user specific login in php with an sql database?

Tags: php, authentication

I coded to check for the first 4 characters typed in the name box and match that with the string.  If it returns true then check for the password and redirect me to a specific web page like the admin dashboard or supervisor dashboard. 
the code i'm using only redirects me to admin dashboard when i try giving the "adm_" prefix but when i try anything else like giving a user name like test1 or a prefix "sup_" it shows a blank page where the path is login.php (the php file where i have the following code)
is there anything i'm missing?

```
   <?php
define('DIR','../');
require_once DIR .'config.php';
$contol = new Controller();

$admin = new Admin();

if (isset($_POST['login_v1'])) 
{


  $name = $_POST['name'];  
  $password = $_POST['password']; 
  //string admin1=adm@;
  //string sup1=sup@;
  //if($name(0,3)=="adm@")
    if(preg_match_all('/^adm_/', $name, $matches))
  {
    $stmt=$admin->ret("SELECT name, password FROM `admine`where name='$name'and password='$password'");
  $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
  $num=$stmt->rowCount();
  if($num>0){

   $_SESSION['name']=$name;
    $admin->redirect('../admintemp/index');

  }
  //if($name(0,3)=="sup@")
  else if(preg_match_all('/^sup_/', $name, $matches))
  {
    $stmt=$super->ret("SELECT name, password FROM `addsuper`where name='$name'and password='$password'");
    $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
    $num=$stmt->rowCount();
    if($num>0){
              $_SESSION['name']=$name;

              $admin->redirect('../bs-siminta-SUPER/index');
              echo "code works";
            }
  }
  else if($name[0]=="[a-z]" || $name[0]=="[A-Z]")
  {
    $name = $_POST['name'];  
    $password = $_POST['pass']; 


    $stmt=$admin->ret("SELECT * FROM `publicreg` where name='$name'and password='$password'");
    $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  

    $num=$stmt->rowCount();
    if($num>0){


    $admin->redirect('../Maxim/user');

  }
  else
  {
    echo "please check your username and password";
  }
}
}
}

?>
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code which you have posted?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: @Oliver.R  the code dosent redirecct me to a new page..rather it shows me a blank page.

Comment: – Jay Blanchard  i will hash it later on. thank you very much! for mentioning this.